# Where is the Data Changing? - Permutations in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, scope, permutation

So for this extra credit problem in my calculus class, my other nerdy classmates and I decided that we would build a program to brute force a solution. One of these steps involves permutations. Through this algorithm, I managed to get it to work (I think):

```
    public void genPermutations(int[] list, int k){
        System.out.println("List: " + Arrays.toString(list));
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        if(k > list.length){
            System.out.println("Not enough elements!");
            return;
        }

        int[] counts = new int[list.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++){
            counts[i] = 1;
        }

        int[] data = new int[k];

        permutationHelper(list, counts, data, 0, k);
    }

   public void permutationHelper(int[] list, int[] counts, int[] data, int index, int k){

      if(index == k){
          //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
          permutations.add(data);
      }else{
          for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
              if(counts[i] == 0){
                  continue;
              }
              data[index] = list[i];
              counts[i]--;
              permutationHelper(list, counts, data, index + 1, k);
              counts[i]++;
          }
      }

   }
```

I have an `ArrayList` that stores all of the possible permutations (as integer arrays) that can be made from k elements of the list that I pass into the function. The problem is that if I print all of these permutations outside of the function, say after I call the `genPermutations` function, every permutation now is the same. But, when I print out the data where the comment is in the `permutationHelper` function, it correctly lists every possible permutation; I'm just unable to access them within the program later. My question is why are the values changing when I exit the function? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some pictures:

[What is printed where the comment is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlD6S.png)

[What is printed later in the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8kRW.png)

The code used to print everything outside of the function is:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < permutations.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(permutations.get(i)));
    }
```

I don't really know if that's necessary to know, but I just thought I'd include it just in case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's only one `data[]` array.  You keep overwriting it as you generate permutations.

Comment: Your scree shots only contain text-output. It is better to add the texte-output as text to your question than referring to an image.

Comment: Before asking here, you should have tried debugging!

Comment: @MrSmith42 Sorry about that. I did try debugging but I just figured since it was recursive, it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is that you are modifying the `array` after adding it to the `list`, you are modifying the same object again and again in different iterations. You were getting `[3,2,1]` in the `list` is because that was the outcome from last iteration.  So as a fix you can use the following code. What it does is it will create a copy of `data` array and add that to the list.

```
int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
permutations.add(temp);
```

**OR** 
you can use `clone()` from array as follows.

```
int[] temp = data.clone();
permutations.add(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're constantly modifying the same array object. Instead of adding different arrays to your list, you're in fact adding a reference to the same array over and over again.

To fix, instead of adding the `data` array to your list, you would have to add a copy of it, e.g. using [`Arrays.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-):

```
permutations.add(Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length));
```

Comment: That makes sense. I figured just because it was being passed in recursively, it would add it to the list without any problems. I didn't think it would be modifying anything. Thank you so much!